# Why Integrated GIT in visual code-insiders dont show changes?

Tags: git

I have a really weird problem that i can't figure out.
When I open console GIT Bash I can see the next status of my changes.
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkFbq.png)
But in integrated GIT within code-insiders I can’t see this changes. 
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMTpv.png)
When I staged all changes in code-insiders extention all work properly, but I havent any changes yet, and moreover, I never saw any changes in this integrated GIT, but in console GIT Bash I can see. 
[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNVMT.png)
Can me anyone explain where my fault is?

Comment: Hi Max, welcome to SO. Just a thought : isn't `accounts2` a branch? If so, you could just be displaying different info in CLI and your application.

Comment: I cant create branch within integrated GIT in vs code but i started to think that its because of big amount of files that shold be initalyzed cause when i try to use this GIT extention with repo that contain only 4 files it works properly. If it is all due to slow processing it will be funny (no)